# Will querying and updating a Database every 3 seconds for multiple users cause any server problems?

Tags: php, mysql

This isn't so much a question of how to do something but a question of SHOULD i do it.

I'm tracking the amount of time a video is watched by updating the database with a start and end time when a video is started or ended. The problem is that if a user just closes the window without letting the video end or manually clicking pause or stop, then I wont get an end time logged.

So, what I'm currently doing in development is running a function every 3 seconds that that uses AJAX and PHP to update the database with an end time - that way if someone closes the window I have a rough end time give or take 3 seconds.

My question is Should I do this? I don't know much about hardware and I'm worried that if Multiple people are watching the video, all sending updates to the DB every 3 seconds, that It could cause some issues.

Am I essentially going to DDOS attack my own website?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: How many people are you expecting? If you know the answer to this first question, you can calculate how many request will be done, and make a test to estimate if your server can do that and keep a live, or die...

Comment: How long is a rope...? There are plenty of unknown factors here. Disk io speed, number of users/request. But a guess is that storing the data wont be an issue until you reach a lot of users. But there will be plenty of http requests. I'm guessing that will be a bottleneck (webserver). Why not store info in local storage every second and update on exit only?

Comment: @niclaslindgren we're expecting a 200 - 300 users at one time. I was considering storing the value as a session variable but wasn't sure how I would go about triggering the PHP script to post that value if the user leaves the page. Do you think using javascript's onbeforeunload would work?

Comment: If it's only 2-300 users it's probably easiest to just do as you suggest. That's not a lot of data/writes. No point over-engineer it.

Answer (score 0):

Well since it is a problem that can be addressed in many ways, the main thing is to investigate some details of the platform (RAM, NET, I / O disk), to be able to anticipate any future problems, now if constantly updating data will affect performance of the systems that occupy the same server, on the other hand you could choose to make updates less frequently and the data is saved in a table or temporary files, then you program a cron style process to update your database at night.